# Subprocess in python don't allow read

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, subprocess, runtime-error

i need your help to debug something
I use subprocess in python to run an external application with this command

`subprocess.run(["Program", "-o", "-e", "Desktop",new_path])`

new_path is a var where i store the path of the app. So it's seem's good but when i start the app with `python3 main.py` i get

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 145, in __new__
process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 121, in create_process
shlex.split(command),

 File "C:\Python27\lib\shlex.py", line 279, in split
return list(lex)

 File "C:\Python27\lib\shlex.py", line 269, in next
token = self.get_token()

File "C:\Python27\lib\shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
raw = self.read_token()


File "C:\Python27\lib\shlex.py", line 124, in read_token
nextchar = self.instream.read(1)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the subprocess with `shell=True`

```
subprocess.run(["Program", "-o", "-e", "Desktop",new_path], shell=True)
```

Comment: I get the same error with shell=True . Maybe an subprocess lib problem ?

Comment: Can you attach how `new_path` is created?

Comment: `paths = ['C:/', 'Users', os.getenv('username'), 'Desktop']`

`new_path = os.path.join(*paths)`
This is my path . You think it's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.5, `subprocess` built-in module supports `run()` that takes cmds either as list or string.

From the error prints `(C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py)`, it looks like the PyPI package's `submodule.run()` is invoked instead of built-in package's method. This method does not accept cmds as list. Reference: https://pypi.org/project/subprocess.run/

Uninstall the PyPI package

```
pip uninstall subprocess.run
```